# Why use the value "mIsBootImageOnDisk " in service DeviceStorageMonitorService

Tags: java, android

I see the git log and find the change `If53c236058a7237d735c2344a715cf0a36301f9b`, it added a final value `mIsBootImageOnDisk` in the constructor function `DeviceStorageMonitorService`. But, it seems useless! Who can tell me?
I see the modification is for `Bug: 17679443`. Who can tell me where to see the bug information ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0akku.png)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no entry for 17679443 in the Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker. I'm going to guess that this is an internal bug number. The error comes from what the documentation describes as retrieving the boot class path from disk storage rather than the dirty pages in memory (the method itself calls isBootClassPathOnDisk which has a native implementation in the art runtime dalvik_system_VMRuntime.cc). I'm experiencing this error now as it processed the arm instruction set (the only instruction set processed by the system). I'm wondering if I'm experiencing a permission issue of some sort that does not allow the image header to be read properly.

The error message that results from not having enough storage space is completing misleading as I'm looking at a df listing where my system partition has 730 MB free and the data partition has 4.8 GB free (actually all the mounted partitions > 250 MB).

Hopefully, someone else will have a solution to this issue. I would hate to have to resort to stubbing out the method with a return true just to get rid of the notification -- there is probably an issue elsewhere in my firmware that needs to be fixed.

So my answer to this question, which I don't need clarification from the OP on to answer, is that there is nothing you can do right now. There are no obvious user forums either here on StackOverflow, in the AOSP issue tracker, or on another user forum like NXP/Freescale (for example) where a better answer or even background to this bug is provided.

Comment: Right now this is what best constitutes an answer IMO,there is no straightforward answer, but this is what he know today. If I had "sufficient reputation" (a silly convention, I'm not going to spend my days hunting for things to answer just to build reputation) I would use the comment facility.